# Missing data due to absent parent

Tags: econometrics, missing-data, data-imputation

I am using the following regression:

$$\text{Test score} = \beta_0+\beta_1\text{Mother's employment}+\beta_2\text{Mother's education}$$

where "Mother's employment" is a set of dummy variables indicating whether the mother works more than 35 hours a week, is unemployed or **is absent**, and "Mother's education" is also a set of dummy variables indicating if the mother has a high school diploma, a college degree or a PhD.

If the mother is absent, then "Mother's education" is not applicable, i.e. there is no answer. How do I deal with this in **Stata**? Mean imputation? How do I do that with dummy variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Stata you can perform multiple imputation. You can either check out Patrick Royston's package `ice`, which performs multiple imputations using chained equaltions (MICE) by typing (in Stata) `net describe ice, from("http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucakjpr/stata/")` .

Or you want to use the more recent versions (v11 forward) of Stata's `mi impute` (which I think is based on Royston's `ice` package), by typing `help mi impute`.

If I recall correctly (I may not) there may be some extra arcana in `ice` that's not in  Stata's `mi impute`.

Comment: Is multiple imputation really appropriate for a situation like this where the data is not missing at random (MAR)? If it is, how do I use multiple imputation given that I'm using multiple dummy variables?

Comment: MI does not necessarily address missing not at random (although if you have data on the kind and causes of missingness that can help), though it does address mar and mcar. It addresses dummy variables by letting you create an appropriate binomial model (e.g logit, probit, complimentary log-log) for such variables. Same is true for other kinds of variables (e,g count, normal, ordered logit, etc.)

Comment: So if multiple imputation isn't appropriate for MNAR, then what should I use instead?

Comment: If you do not have identifiable measures on the causal path to observations being MNAR, you can't really do anything. That is, as I understand it, MI is your best alternative, but does not guarantee unbiased inference.

Comment: What do you mean by causal paths to observations being MNAR? The reason the data on mom's education missing/not available is because the mother simply does not exist. Does this help in deciding what to do?

Comment: Ah I *think* I see... this may be more of a variable definition and coding problem, than a missing data problem *per se*. For example:$$\text{Test score} = \beta_0+\beta_1\text{Mother's employed*MotherAbsent}+\beta_2\text{Mother's education*MotherAbsent}$$ where **Mother's education** is now simply unemployed/35+ hours. Will have to think on it.

Answer (score 2):

Mean imputation doesn't fully show the variation that would be in the data if it weren't missing.

Multiple imputation is generally regarded as superior. This is possible with categorical variables. In fact, "education" is ordinal. [This article](http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2012/SD-12.pdf) compares SAS and SUDAAN. For more general information see [Little & Rubin](http://smile.amazon.com/Statistical-Analysis-Missing-Roderick-Little/dp/0471183865/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1399466018&sr=1-1&keywords=little%20rubin%20missing%20data). As to how to do this in STATA, perhaps someone else here will know, but that might be better asked on a Stata list.