# Father/Mother education and working status for single parent household

Tags: econometrics, missing-data

My question is pratically the same as in:

[Missing data due to absent parent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96742/missing-data-due-to-absent-parent)

However I could not find a definitive solution.

I face the same problem, meaning that I do not have observation for Mother or Father Education/Working status, if thery are absent from the household.

The model I want to study is something like:

$$ \text{University Enrollment} = \beta_0+\beta_1\text{Mother's employment}+\beta_2\text{Mother's education} +\beta_3\text{Father's employment} +\beta_4\text{Father's education} +\delta\text{Has Both Parents}+\text{etc.}$$

Given that education and employment are categorical variable in my dataset, how should I proceed?

The simplest solution would be to restrict the sample to households with both parents only, but I would prefer not doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional level for the variable, let’s say “unavailable”. Would also help when observations out of your sample do not have the same details.

Comment: However, when using this approach some variables of the regression are dropped out due to collinearity, so that there exist some problems with the interpretation of the coefficients.

Comment: If your data is sufficiently large, you could build two separate models - one and two parent households.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have many observations...